# Can one create a SVGZ file which displays directly in a browser?

Tags: svg

According to all documentation I can find on the web so far  an SVGZ file is a GZIP archive containing a valid SVG file.  I have some specimen SVGZ files. For the specimen files I can double-click on specimen.SVGZ and sure enough Chrome or Firefox will display the file.

If I open the file in 7-zip I find a text payload called 'specimen' - I can extract that to a file called 'specimen'. If I rename that to 'specimen.svg' and double-click  again, as expected, it displays in Chrome or Firefox.

If I use Java code to embed the original 'specimen' payload into a zip file called 'specimen.SVGZ' it does ***not*** open in Chrome or Firefox.  Chrome, for example may report `"This site can’t be reached The webpage at  file:///T:/TestDir/specimen.svgz might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."`  Firefox either hangs or tells me it can't parse the file.

I see similar errors if I do this by hand – that is take the payload and using a GZIP compression methodology add the payload to a file which I then rename to 'specimen.SVGZ'.

If I binary compare the original specimen.SVGZ with any I create I can see differences in the binary compressed data ( although both file start with the same 2 byte header of `0x1F 0x8B`).  ***Does anyone know the magic that I have missed when creating SVGZ programmatically ( or indeed by hand).***  E.g.  compression algorithms have a number of settings – is it possible that only a particular set are allowed?   Is there a ***'real'*** specification for SVGZ anywhere? - other posts on Stack overflow redirect me to Adobe - but there is nothing on the Adobe page.

Comment: you cannot do this via the file protocol. You would need to use a web server and serve the file via the http or https protocol.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you, except that the original files do display via the file protocol. So some folks can create SVGZ that displays directly. But I cannot.

Comment: Yes, it's the decompression that's not supported by the file protocol by browsers.

Comment: RE: decompression that's not supported.  If you look at my post you will see that I have many SVGZ's created by a previous system that DO open directly. So it can be done.  My problem is to understand how it has been done because we have a customer who expects what we do to be as good as their previous system.  I suspect in some way that the compression is different.  But as I cannot find the official documentation for SVGZ I'm left guessing as to what are the correct compression parameters one must use for direct file display to work.